# Angular UI, Unique not working

Tags: angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

So i'm trying to filter my ng-repeat directive by using angular unique module.. but i'm kinda lost, i followed the exact order with adding the scripts... In console i'm getting an error, 'No module: ui.utils'..

Here is my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cKJgtGyYeQdQCyARXG7j?p=preview

From this code:

```
<ul>
 <li>nokia</li>
 <li>nokia</li>
 <li>samsung</li>
</ul>
```

i should get with -unique- this code:

```
<ul>
 <li>nokia</li>
 <li>samsung</li>
</ul>
```

Some good people here helped me already by using jQuery filter, but i think this is much better way of doing this..
Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: Problem already found, unique: name, should be unique: 'name'... Stupid mistake :/

Comment: Your demo also appears to be on an outdated version of AngularUI. You may want to close the question lol.

Comment: I'll leave it be, just for maybe another people with the same problem, AngularUI structure can be really tricky for newbies like me :)

Comment: Please provide an answer below and accept it or delete your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'unique'(aliases: uniq) filter in angular.filter module (https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

usage: `colection | uniq: 'property'` 
you can filter by nested properties to : `colection | uniq: 'property.nested_property'`

So you can do something like that..

```
function MainController ($scope) {
 $scope.orders = [
  { id:1, customer: { name: 'foo', id: 10 } },
  { id:2, customer: { name: 'bar', id: 20 } },
  { id:3, customer: { name: 'foo', id: 10 } },
  { id:4, customer: { name: 'bar', id: 20 } },
  { id:5, customer: { name: 'baz', id: 30 } },
 ];
}
```

**HTML:** We filters by customer id, i.e remove duplicate customers

```
<th>All customers list: </th>
<tr ng-repeat="order in orders | unique: 'customer.id'" >
   <td> {{ order.customer.name }} , {{ order.customer.id }} </td>
</tr>
```

**result:**
All customers list:
foo 10
bar 20
baz 30